# $B \cong \operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}}(N) \cong e\operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}} (A^m)e$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A, B$ be Morita equivalent $k$-algebras. Denote by $e : A^m → A^m$ an idempotent endomorphism that is a projection onto a direct summand of $A^m$ isomorphic to $N$ as a right $A$-module. Identify $N = e(A^m)$. Then $B \cong \operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}}(N) \cong e\operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}} (A^m)e$.

I can't get the last isomorphism as I think the domains are not even the same. If I am being silly again, please point it out as I am really stuck.

Comment: I'm not sure what $B$ is doing here.

Comment: we could ignore B, in fact. I put it there to give some context...

Comment: I wish to see why there are two e's in the end.

Comment: Elements of $\operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}} (A^m)e$ don't necessarily have $N$ as their codomain, and there are multiple elements of $e\operatorname{End}_{A^\text{op}} (A^m)$ corresponding to a single element of $\operatorname{End}_{A^{op}}(N)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M=A^m$ be decomposed as $M=N\oplus N'$ with $e=\iota_N\pi_N:M\to M,\ n+n'\mapsto n$ where $\iota_N:N\to M$ is the inclusion and $\pi_N:M\to N$ is the projection.

Then for an endomorphism $f:M\to M$, we get an endomorphism on $N$ by considering $f':=\pi_Nf\iota_N$.

Conversely, for any endomorphism $g:N\to N$ we can take $\tilde g:=\iota_Ng\pi_N:M\to M$.
Note that $e\tilde ge=\tilde g$.

I let you prove that these operations are inverses to each other when restricted to endomorphisms of $M$ in the form of $efe$.